# Django ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''how i can solve the None type error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

in Django forms when i am appending the values , from old_car field getting **ValueError  invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''**

the values of new_car and old_car are string and need to convert to integer for further conditions, i know if i remove int will solve the error :).

how i can solve that

django forms.py

```py
car = cleaned_data.get("user", ['AUTO'])
if car[0] == 'AUTO':
    records = []
    for i in range(count):
        new_car = int(self.data.get(f'cardefination_set-{i}-new_car', []))
        old_car =int(self.data.get(f'cardefination_set-{i}-old_car', []))
        records.append((new_car, old_car))
    records = sorted(records, key=lambda record: record[1])
```

traceback

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72548081/edit#
```

Comment: Where is the traceback? I mean, what line is the error being thrown? What is `count`?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your code I will address a couple of issues related with these lines:

```py
#...
new_car = int(self.data.get(f'cardefination_set-{i}-new_car', []))
old_car =int(self.data.get(f'cardefination_set-{i}-old_car', []))
#...
```

The issue is the same in both lines. You are `casting` (explicit type conversion) a value to `int` using `int(value)`. This means that the value must be "convertible" to `int`. In your case you are getting a value from `self.data`, that I am going to assume it is a dictionary. If the obtained value can't be converted to `int` you will get that error.

Moreover, I see you are using the default value parameter on the `dict.get(key, value)` function.

> get(key[, default])
>
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

The default value you are providing is `[]` which is a `list`, *i.e.* `int([])` will throw:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'

That error is not the error you are mentioning, but just wanted to point that out.

**I think your issue is that the value you are getting from the dictionary is an empty string**.

Hence your error:

> ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Make sure what you are getting from the dict can be converted to `int`